# Trace $controller, $action, $id from urlmapping

Tags: grails

Is there a way to log the urlmapping from

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }

    "/"(view:"/index")
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

Need to trace the $controller, $action, $id.

Comment: With what version of Grails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an interceptor you can refer to `controllerName`, `actionName` and `params.id` and do whatever you want with that info, including logging it.